# How can I detect when a button is held in js?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to detect when a button is being held down by a finger for an unspecified amount of time. However I can't figure out how to do that.

I tried doing this like the sample online showed

```js
const b = document.getElementById("hold-me");

b.onclick = function() {
  setTimeout(alert, 2000, "you held me down for 2 second");
}
```

```html
<body>
<button id="hold-me">Hold me</button>
</body>
```

However it doesn't correspond to what I want to do as I want to be able to have the event to fire as long as the button is pressed.

### **Edit:**

To add some clarification, the set timeout function is here because it's roughly what the example I found online did. Here is the example: https://codepen.io/thetallweeks/pen/uAEGr?editors=0010

The example I found online didn't helped because I want to query if the button is press continuously to know wether I should a action of moving my rc car or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1'st variant, event fire after "unspecified amount of time";

```js
const b = document.getElementById("hold-me");
let time;
b.onpointerdown = function() {
  time = Date.now();
}
b.onpointerup = function() {
  console.log(`you held me down for ${Date.now() - time} milliseconds`);
}
```

```html
<body>
<button id="hold-me">Hold me</button>
</body>
```

2'nd variant, event fire during "unspecified amount of time":

```js
const b = document.getElementById("hold-me");
let timer;
b.onpointerdown = function() {
  timer = setTimeout(alert, 2000, "you held me down for 2 second");
}
b.onpointerup = function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

```html
<body>
<button id="hold-me">Hold me</button>
</body>
```

Comment: While this will result in the elapsed time being calculated, it doesn't provide the functionality to perform a task after a certain amount of time has gone by as the OP is showing.

Comment: and from which sentence we should deduce that?

Comment: ***I am trying to detect when a button is being held down by a finger for an unspecified amount of time.*** The `setTimeout()` implies that something should happen after 2 seconds have elapsed. Your code only does something after the button is released, not after an amount of time has gone by.

Comment: The `setTimeout()` was here because the example found online used it -- it's not usefulf for what I wanna do Scott. What I wanna do is a button for controlling gas in a rc car control gamepad built using js.

Comment: this was the first thing that came in my mind, that you need a push-pull button

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`mousedown` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event) and get the current time every time the button is pressed. Then, in the timer function, see if it's at least however many seconds the user has determined past that start time. When the button is released, reset the time.

Also, you should use the modern API for event binding of [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), rather than setting event properties.

```js
let start = null;

const elapsedTime = +prompt("How many seconds should we wait?");
const button = document.getElementById("hold-me");
button.textContent += " for at least " + elapsedTime + " seconds.";

button.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
  start = new Date(); // Record the start time
  
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    // If there is a start time and its now at least 2 seconds past that...
    if(start && (new Date() > start.setSeconds(start.getSeconds() + elapsedTime))){
      alert("You held me down for " + elapsedTime + " seconds.");
    }
  }, elapsedTime * 1000);
});

document.getElementById("hold-me").addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
  start = null; // Cancel the time
});
```

```html
<button id="hold-me">Hold me</button>
```

Comment: I use event property because my project use react.

Comment: "modern" is a bit fuzzy nowadays :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon how much time you consider that the user is holding. You can say, for example, that a time of less than 1 second is **click** and greater a button being hold down.

Furthermore, it's good to point that holding is the combination of two Javascript events: **mouseup** and **mousedown**. The first gets track of wheter the click pushes down the button and the second when user left the mouse click button.

```js
let startTime, clickTime = 2000 // in milliseconds

$("#btn").mousedown(()=>{
    startTime = new Date()
    console.log("Holding")
    // Your logic goes here (while holding)
})


$("#btn").mouseup(()=>{
  var elapsedTime = new Date() - startTime
  elapsedTime <= clickTime ? console.log("It's a click") : console.log(`It was held by ${elapsedTime} ms`)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='btn'>Hold! :)</button>
```

Finally: you are able to detect whether a button is being held down or not based on the time you set to be considered a button holding, then you can implement your logic.

Comment: `mouseover` is not part of a combination of events that combine to create holding.

Comment: I see, it was supposed to be mouseup (as in the code)

Comment: `mouseup` is also not part of a combination of events that result in holding.

Comment: Also, your code produces an elapsed time after you let go of the button, but the OP is looking for something to happen as you continue to hold the button down for an amount of time, not after you let the button up.

Comment: Yeah and mousedown event fires whenever user starts to hold until drop click, so it fires console.log and it doesn't make it incompatible with what OP asked

Comment: My point is that `mouseup` doesn't combine with `mousedown` to create a hold. They can be used together for sure, but that description is not accurate.

Comment: What's other combination then? Mouseout ?

Comment: Would Mouseout be compatible with touch devices?

Comment: I can't see any restrictions

Comment: There's a case when you hold but then moves your mouse outside the button space, it's not performed a holding. Not the case I showed but it can be done if you desire